# Return custom date members Month

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

If I run the following:

```
WITH MEMBER [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Last Completed Month] AS
     IIF( Day(Now()) = 1,
         TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month],1)(0),
         TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month],2)(0)
    )
SELECT
       NON EMPTY
          [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Last Completed Month]
       ON COLUMNS
FROM  [OurCube]
WHERE ([Measures].[NumUsers])
```

It returns this:

[image]

Is it possible to change the script so that instead of using "Last Completed Month" as the column header it uses the actual month "June 2013" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @cur_date   varchar(20), @linked_server varchar(20) = 'YourLinkedServer'
set @cur_date=datename(M,GETDATE()) + ' '+ datename(YYYY,GETDATE())
declare @mdx_query varchar(max) = 
'WITH MEMBER [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Last Completed Month] AS
     IIF( Day(Now()) = 1,
         TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month],1)(0),
         TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month],2)(0)
    )
SELECT
       NON EMPTY
   [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Last Completed Month] as ''' + @cur_date + '''
       ON COLUMNS
FROM  [OurCube]
WHERE ([Measures].[NumUsers])'

set @mdx_query='Select * from openrowset('''+@linked_server+''','''+@mdx_query+''')'
EXEC sp_executesql @mdx_query
```

As for pure MDX solution, there is a [way](http://bisherryli.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/mdx-17-can-we-create-a-column-alias/).

Comment: `sp_executesql` will run `MDX` against an `SSAS OLAP` database?

Comment: 'Select * from openrowset('''+@linked_server+''','''+@mdx_query+''')'

Comment: thanks for the workaround - although I'm hoping for a pure `MDX` answer without having to fall back on `dynamic sql`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not think this is possible; the CAPTION property does not seem to accept an MDX expression.

```
WITH MEMBER XX as 42, CAPTION = 'Answer'
SELECT XX ...
```

Depending on how the MDX is used you can add a calculated member displaying the name

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [LCM Value] as  (...)
  MEMBER [LCM Name ] as  (...).name

SELECT
 { [LCM Value], [LCM Name] } on 0
...
```

Comment: +1 thanks for info Marc. Looks like revoua's answer is as close as we'll get